# poll() function call in terms network operation

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

Can someone explain what happens when we do a poll on an fd.
i have read the man pages and understand that the we wait for some event on a given file descriptor

but what i wish to understand is that what hand shaking takes place and what kind of packets flow from the client to the server , and back, in order to get the result of the poll [sucess or error(POLLHUP) ]

I came across the sequence diagrams for the following 
-connection establishement
-data transfer
-connection closing

here is the URL
http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/networking/Tcp.pdf

Can we safely say that this is a form of data transfer only?
If not can someone route me to the correct flow .

Assumption:
I am considering the TCP connection in the above question.

Thanks in advance for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Poll() doesn't cause any data flow. It's just used to listen to events of fds.

For TCP connection, data flow should be initiated by client side connect() call.